# SpriteKit: Calculate offset from drag path

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I try to calculate the offset from a drop path using Objective-C with SpriteKit.

See this Picture:
[image]

Here I have the drag path(red line) with an constant angle (a) and I have the two points(coordinates).

And now I would like to calculate the length of the offset from the red line (green line)...

How can I calculate this?

Thanks for your help,
Uriman

Comment: This graph looks to me like simple math with two coordinates line formula, distance within two coordinates and angles and slopes of given lines. Just basic calculation.

Comment: This should be tagged differently, since it’s a geometry/trigonometry problem, not specific to Objective-C or Sprite Kit.

Answer (score 0):

| **p2** − **p1** | × sin(a)

This is basic geometry.